# 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Related: [2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/2019-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) and [Questionnaire](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/2019-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)

Comment: Also, for reference, the previous elections: [2012](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/1), [2015](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/2), and [2017](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/3)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the 2019 election has concluded and this post is not soliciting answers.