# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Role-playing Games's [fourth moderator election](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: V2Blast] [image: Rubiksmoose]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking SevenSidedDie and mxyzplk who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5153296585064448/0).

Comment: Congrats, kids!

Comment: I'm happy with these results. Congratulations, and thank you.

Comment: Congratulations! Well deserved, and you both will be fine moderators!

Comment: Congrats to Rubiksmoose and V2Blast!  Also, did I miss something, or is this the first announcement of mxy stepping down?

Comment: Yes, my congratulations also to Rubiksmoose and V2Blast! And yes, our longest running mod has stepped down suddenly out of the blue! Not that mxy needs to explain himself or anything, but I was shocked to read that, I had to double take!

Comment: Congratulations, both! Here, let us pass you these torches. :)

Comment: Congratulations to you both:  you’ve been helpful in getting the new guy, yours truly, up and running in the group.  Best of luck and good fun in this new endeavor.

Comment: Congrats to you both

Comment: Well, I'd intended to give it a month or two of overlap, but there seems to have been some miscommunication with SE central. But yes, I've been planning on stepping away from the diamond after 8 1/2 years on duty. Congrats to the new mods!

Comment: @mxyzplk: Oh. My apologies. At the time of election wrap-up, I have a note with who is stepping down. Usually that means people are stepping down immediately after the election. Sorry about the mixup.

Comment: Congratulations and thank you for volunteering to make this community and the world of gaming better.

Comment: Is there some reason this time the link for viewing the results online is not available from the election page? It used to be there [in previous elections](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/3)

Comment: @Sdjz: Yes. Human error. I've fixed that now. (Hopefully we'll have more of this automated soon.)

Comment: @JonEricson Oh I had no idea that message was not automatic. Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

First of all:

## Thanks, mxyzplk, for serving as a mod!

I may never have remembered how to spell your username without looking it up, but I did appreciate the hard work put into the site by you, SevenSidedDie, nitsua60, and doppelgreener. Hope you stick around the site and keep making it a better place! Half the mod team being changed feels like a big deal.

On that note:

## Congrats to Rubiksmoose, and thanks to everyone who voted!

I appreciate everyone who voted - no matter who you voted for. I know Rubiksmoose will do a great job. I've got a lot of stuff to read through, but I hope to keep RPG.SE at least as good as how I found it. Thanks for your confidence in the two of us!

Comment: Wait a minute, you didn't edit Jon Ericson's post.  Are you feeling well?  8^D

Comment: Congratulations, V2Blast! Sorry I wasn't here to vote for you. But in the end it didn't really matter, because...your awesome. ;-)

Comment: @Caldrun: Thanks! :)

Answer (score 16):

Ah, so mxy *is* stepping down. I suspected that was in the cards.

#### 1. Grats Rubiksmoose and V2Blast. We are in good hands.

#### 2. Thanks, mxyzplk, for your long service at this stack ...

... and for volunteering your time in the efforts of achieving the goal of a good site with a good SNR.  More on that later.  [We already have a thank you thread for Seven](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9013/22566).

Noteworthy stat:

> 4,650 voters were eligible, 1,538 visited the site during the
> election, 843 visited the election page, and 494 voted

10.62 per cent cared enough to vote.

As @Carcer kindly pointed out, given those still active, about 32% voted.

Comment: My intention was to vote and I believe that I did.  What I was looking for was some kind of definite notification that my vote had been cast.  What I did see was confirmation for my 1st, 2nd and 3rd choices.  Does that mean that my vote was counted?  What was the 3rd choice about? If I got it wrong, probably wasn’t the only one (not that this would account for 2/3 no show)

Comment: @Greg0141 Yes. that is the same confirmation I got.  As I understand the way the balloting works, the second and third choices help the voting algorithm deal with the runoffs.  You can see that [in the links Jon provided in the opening post](https://www.opavote.com/results/5153296585064448/0).

Comment: It uses a voting system called the single transferrable vote (though it limits the number of choices you can rank, unlike full STV). For a real world reference Ireland uses STV to elect it's parliamentary representatives.

Comment: @Greg0141 you got the [constituent badge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/90/constituent?userid=52120) so that's pretty good confirmation the system thinks you did indeed vote.

Comment: For the stats—im mostly on mobile nowadays, and missed the election :’(

Answer (score 8):

Congrats to you both!

I want to say to Rubiksmoose that I voted for you as my 3rd choice not because I thought you a poor choice, but because part of me wanted to keep you a regular user that asked good meta-questions and made good comments without the diamond attached to your name. It was a weird catch-22 for me. I sincerely hope you continue providing excellent comments and find ways to do so in a manner that doesn't seem mandatory despite the diamond, I know other mods have sometimes struggled with this.

V2, I hope you continue your extensive edits to improve links throughout the stack to connect things with official sources wherever possible. It's very appreciated, though, perhaps never mentioned.

Obviously, neither of these statements comprise your full contributions, just the most notable things for myself personally. Congratulations again and thank you for contributions both past, present and future!

Comment: I’ve felt that catch-22 in a few elections.

Comment: Thanks! I do hope to continue providing sourcing where relevant, if simply because most people don't have access to the sources in multiple formats and thus it seems unlikely to get done otherwise :)